# How to Create a Custom Behavior for Double Pressing Curly Braces { in VS Code for Twig?

Tags: visual-studio, twig, vscode-extensions

### How to Create a Custom Behavior for Double Pressing Curly Braces `{` in VS Code for Twig?

I'm trying to achieve a specific behavior in VS Code for Twig files. When I type the opening curly brace `{` twice, I want it to automatically expand to `{{  }}` with two spaces in the middle and the cursor positioned between the spaces.

#### What I tried so far:

1. **Using VS Code's Native Snippets**:

   - I attempted to use the built-in snippet functionality in VS Code, specifically for the Twig language.
   - I created a `twig.json` snippet that looks like this:

     ```json
     {
       "Insert Curly Braces": {
         "prefix": "{{",
         "body": ["{{ $1 }}"],
         "description": "Inserts {{ }} with spaces."
       }
     }
     ```
   - However, the cursor didn't position itself correctly.
2. **Using Keybindings**:

   - Modified the `keybindings.json` to include a custom sequence that triggers on a certain combination, but this led to conflicts and was not seamless.
3. **Disabling Extensions**:

   - Disabled the Twig extensions to see if they were causing conflicts, but the behavior persisted.
4. **Using the Multi-Command Extension**:

   - Configured a sequence using the [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) extension to handle the typing sequence.
   - This approach seemed promising, but I couldn't get the cursor to position correctly after expansion.

The desired behavior is proving difficult to achieve. Has anyone else encountered this issue or have suggestions for implementing this behavior in VS Code?